# Remove bracket from a line using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a line which looks like this:

```
(ABCD)(ABCDE)(ABCDEF)(ABCDEFG)
```

but I want to store it like this :

```
ABCDABCDEABCDEFABCDEFG
```

in a variable called parser. The code I am using is

```
my ($parser) = $subckt =~ m/\s*(\(.*?)\);
```

Here `$subckt` variable stores the actual line with brackets.

How do I get the required data in the variable `$parser`. 
Please help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
$subckt =~ s/[()]//g;
```

Answer (score 2):

The *translate* operator [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html) is what you need. With the `/d` (delete) modifier you can delete all characters in the list that have no corresponding replacement.

If you have version 14 or later of Perl 5 then the `/r` (non-destructive) modifier makes it a lot tidier.

This program demonstrates

```
use 5.014;

my $subckt = '(ABCD)(ABCDE)(ABCDEF)(ABCDEFG)';
my $parser = $subckt =~ tr/()//dr;

print $parser;
```

**output**

```
ABCDABCDEABCDEFABCDEFG
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove the parentheses as the title suggests, 
the substitution operator `s///` is the natural choice:

```
my $subckt = '(ABCD)(ABCDE)(ABCDEF)(ABCDEFG)';
my $parser = $subckt;
$parser =~ s/[()]//g;
```

That said, it's a bit hard to guess what you really want to do and what kind of possible inputs you have.
Based on the broken regex in the post, perhaps what you really want is change patterns of `\s*\(X\)` to `X`. If that's the case, then instead of a substitution, it will be easier to use a matching, with a *capture group*, similar to the way you seem to have tried:

```
my $subckt = '(ABCD)(ABCDE)(ABCDEF)(ABCDEFG)';
my ($parser) = join('', $subckt =~ m/\s*\((.*?)\)/g);
```

This will also work with input like this:

```
my $subckt = '     (ABCD) (ABCDE)(ABCDEF)(ABCDEFG)';
```

The way this works:

- `m/...(...).../g` returns a list of the matched strings captured within `(...)`
- What you want to match is stuff within literal `(` and `)`, so the expression should in fact look like `m/...\((...)\).../g`, notice the `\(` and `\)` outside of the `(...)` capture
- The `/g` flag is important (was missing in yours), otherwise pattern matching will stop after the first match

Comment: One reason to downvote would be: This does not work if the line does not contain parentheses. It does not work if the parentheses are not balanced. It has a random matching of whitespace `\s*` which does nothing at all. The fact that it works at all is because you are only using a specific set of input. A much better version of the same thing would be to use the regex `/[^()]+/g`. But even then it is inferior to just removing `()` with `tr` like Borodin suggests.

Comment: Also, it can lead to the wrong result, as for example `ABC(D` would return `ABC` and not `ABCD`.

Comment: @TLP the OP had `\s*\(` in his pattern, suggesting he wants to get rid of not only parens, but also any whitespaces right in front of the opening paren. What is right and wrong to do about `ABC(D` is speculation, because the OP didn't give any information about such inputs. And if you simply want to remove `()`, then `tr///` is not the right tool, it should be `s///`. In any case, I rewrote my post to clarify

Comment: Your post is much improved. If it was my downvote, I would retract it.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your new variable, and then remove all non-word characters

```
( my $parser = $subckt ) =~ s/\W//g;
```

Or using the [`/r` Modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers):

```
my $parser = $subckt =~ s/\W//gr;
```

Comment: It's probably a foregone conclusion, but would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: The requirement was to remove brackets, not all non word characters. This solution might be OK for the sample data, but could remove other characters the user wants to keep.

Comment: @KimRyan Given the OP was struggling mostly with how to use the matching operator, it seems reasonable to make this mostly about how to create a modified version of an original variable using the substitution operator.  Nevertheless, I agree that if their real data varies wildly from their sample data, the solution would require fine tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all occuences of bracket, which the g flag does

```
 $subckt =~ s/\(//g;
 $subckt =~ s/\)//g;
```